# Heading Element is pushed off center when next to an image - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I've seen this question on here however mines a bit of a different circumstance. I have 2 paragraphs using the

element. I have a background colour of white on a blue background. The background colour is like a full block so it doesn't just cover the lines of text and that is the way I want it.

My problem is that I have an image floated to my top left and a heading in the middle. The heading is off center and I can't center it at all. from reading the other questions on here, I have tried the clear: left and just clear: both and it does work but it breaks the block into two blocks and I want it as one whole.

Here is my HTML And CSS:

```css
p{
 font: 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 text-align: center; 
 border-color: black;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3px;
 margin: auto;
 background-color:white;
 line-height:1.7em;
 color: black;
 width: 99%;
 display: block;
  }
  h2 {
 font: 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: white;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 width: 99%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 2px;
}
h3 {
 font: 1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: white;
 margin: auto;
 background-color: white;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 padding: 0 0 0 5px;
 width: 98.7%;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: black;
 border-width: 2px;
}
 .rotateimgME90 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#my_image{
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:7px;
 margin-top: -30px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h2><u><b>A Little Bit About Me...</b></u></h2>
 <img src="..\R2D2Build\Pictures\RobHomepage.jpg"
   alt="me"
   class="rotateimgME90"
   img id="my_image">
<p>*.*.*.*</p>
<h3><u><b>What's Here?</u></b></h3> <-THIS IS WHAT IS OFF CENTER>
```

It is my

#### What's Here

bit that is off center.

Any help would be much appreciated, people on this website have really helped me out before I made an account on here!

Rob

Comment: Use something else and not float then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float:left` is causing issues here.

You can add:

```
h3 {
    float: left;
}
```

Though, you may want to restructure your html so you don't need to use `float:left`